# Only change from Play to Pause if the audio link is working

Tags: javascript, button, audio, input

If the value is an incorrect stream link, the 'Play' button still changes to 'Pause.'

This is what I was trying to prevent from happening.

Pressing 'Set' should not cause the Play button to change from 'Play' to 'Pause' if the audio is not working.

**Code:** 
https://jsfiddle.net/vhgL96se/124/

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJ6GI.png)

```
(function iife() {
    "use strict";
    const player = document.getElementById("player");
    const button = document.getElementById("button");
    const value = document.getElementById("input");
    const sent = document.getElementById("sent");
    const input = document.getElementById("clear");
    let canPlay = false;

    function playPauseIcon(play) {
        if (!canPlay) {
            return;
        }
        if (play) {
            button.classList.add("is-playing");
        } else {
            button.classList.remove("is-playing");
        }
    }
    button.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (!canPlay) {
            return;
        }
        if (player.paused) {
            player.play();
            playPauseIcon(true);
        } else {
            player.pause();
            playPauseIcon(false);
        }
    });
    button.addEventListener("mousedown", function (evt) {
        if (evt.detail > 1) {
            evt.preventDefault();
        }
    }, false);
    sent.addEventListener("click", function () {
        player.src = value.value;
        player.volume = 1.0;
        playPauseIcon(true);
    });
    input.addEventListener("click", function () {
        value.value = "";
        button.classList.remove("is-playing");
        player.pause();
        canPlay = false;
    }, false);
    player.onloadstart = function () {
        if (value.value !== "") {
            canPlay = true;
            playPauseIcon(true);
        }
    };
}());
```

Comment: You're calling `playPauseIcon(true)` from a lot of places, you should probably only called it from `player.onloadstart`

Comment: What if I changed player.onloadstart to player.oncanplay instead? https://jsfiddle.net/vhgL96se/132/ Play button changes from Play to Pause
http://hi5.1980s.fm/; That seems to have worked.

Play button does not change from Play to Pause
when the stream is not valid.
h://hi5.1980s.fm/;

Comment: Which should be used here? oncanplay https://jsfiddle.net/vhgL96se/142/ OR oncanplaythrough https://jsfiddle.net/vhgL96se/144/ A radio stream would be considered what?

Answer (score 0):

It should be changed to oncanplay instead, and then it works as it should.

Play button changes from Play to Pause

http://hi5.1980s.fm/;

Play button does not change from Play to Pause
when the stream is not valid.

h://hi5.1980s.fm/;

https://jsfiddle.net/vhgL96se/132/

```
player.oncanplay = function () {
    if (value.value !== "") {
        canPlay = true;
        playPauseIcon(true);
    }
};
```